# Intellij - UnsatisfiedLinkError: %1 .dll is no valid win32 application

Tags: java, windows, winapi, intellij-idea, win64

I am trying to create a native dll for my Java programm in Intellij. I have created a .dll file and my vm options are: -Djava.library.path="C:\Users\pk\IdeaProjects\MyTerminErinnerung".
But I get the following error: UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\pk\IdeaProjects\MyTerminErinnerung/window.dll %1 is no valid win32 application
There is nothing in my .dll file except "#include "window.h"". (I will fill it as soon as I have solved this error problem.) The path given is correct. I read on other sites that has to do with win64. Maybe the once of who know Intellij AND Windows can tell what might be the mistake?

Comment: Are you using your own "window.h"? There is no "window.h" in system but only "windows.h". Do you misspell?

Comment: i am using my own "window.h". There is nothing inside of "window.h". The same error appeared in my CLion application.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to refer to the system header file but not your own header file, Please try to use `#include <windows.h>` instead of `#include "window.h"`

Edit:

Also make sure your JAVA environment(64/32-bit) match the .dll building platform(x64/x86).

Comment: Should I use a file of the system whether than my own? Also, when I opened my window.dll, Intellij asked me what type to use and I chose "text" because I didn't know.

Comment: what's the bit of your dll and calling application, 64/32?  BTW .dll file is a binary file.

Comment: If you have a 64-bit java, make sure build the .dll as x64 .

Comment: How can I find out about the bit version of my java? And how can I set my .dll as x64? (I created it in Intellij and, as mentioned above, I was asked for the type of my file only.) If I remember the right, I have installed my Intellij under x86 because there was a problem that I don't remember. Is this important?

Comment: are you running Intellij from idea.exe or idea64.exe?

Comment: I could find an idea.exe, an idea64.exe and an ideaIC-2018.1.2.exe on my PC, I don't know how to find out which of those I am running.

Comment: @JavaFeminine Right-click on the IntelliJ shortcut->Properties->Shortcut, you will see the executable file in "Target".
For Java version, Type "java -version" on the command line, If is 64-bit, the last line will display 64-Bit, like: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.1-b02, mixed mode)

Comment: @JavaFeminine, And how do you loadlibrary? Can you flow the step of [this](https://www.chilkatsoft.com/java-loadlibrary-windows.asp)?